# Iterate dynamic web table using loop with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently finding element by id for each row and verifying each column where in if I have 100 rows I should write 100 xpaths and 100 elif statement which is not ideal, I should check if Ext column is No and is status is not started than it should click on the submit image.                                 This is the code iam using

```
    tit1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00__0"]/td[14]/img')  
    ext1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00__0"]/td[13]')     
    ext1N = ext1.get_attribute("outerHTML")  
    tit1N = tit1.get_attribute("title")  
    tit2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '[@id="m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00__1"]/td[14]/img')  
    ext2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00__1"]/td[13]')  
    ext2N = ext2.get_attribute("outerHTML")  
    tit2N = tit2.get_attribute("title") 

    if tit1N in tittext and ext1N in exttext:
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl05").click()
      elif tit2N in tittext and ext2N in exttext:
          driver.find_element(By.NAME, "m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl06$ctl05").click()
```

```html
<table class="rgMasterTable" id="m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00" style="width:100%;table-layout:auto;empty-cells:show;">
            <caption class="rgCaption"><div width="100%" float="left" style="text-align:left; margin-left:3px"> <b>LEGEND:</b> <span class="gridLegend"><img class="gridIconPadding" src="/images/statusRed.png"> Not Started</span> <span class="gridLegend"><img class="gridIconPadding" src="/images/statusYellow.png"> In Progress</span> <span class="gridLegend"><img class="gridIconPadding" src="/images/statusGreen.png"> Complete</span> <span class="gridLegend"><img class="gridIconPadding" src="/Images/StatusGreen_Warning.png"> Complete (Missing Paperwork)</span> <span class="gridLegend"><img class="gridIconPadding" src="/images/StatusCreated.png"> SOW Pending Paperwork</span> <span class="gridLegend"><img class="gridIconPadding" src="/images/warning.png"> SOW Pending Metadata and Paperwork</span> <span class="gridLegend"><img class="gridIconPadding" src="/images/StatusCreditCheck.png"> SOW Missing Credit Check</span> <span class="gridLegend"><img class="gridIconPadding" src="/images/magnify.gif"> View</span> </div></caption>
<colgroup>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:left;"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'ProjectType'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl00','')">Pricing Terms</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'CountryName'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl01','')">Country</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:left;"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'ClientName'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl02','')">Client Name</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'Number'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl03','')">Opp #</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:left;"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'Name'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl04','')">Opportunity Name</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:left;"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'StageName'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl05','')">Stage</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:right;"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'Amount'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl06','')">Opportunity Amount</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'PursuitLeadName'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl07','')">Pursuit Lead</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'EngagementStartDate'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl08','')">Start Date</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'CloseDate'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl09','')">Close Date</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'ProjectOwner'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl10','')">Project Owner</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'ProjectOwnerNotifiedDate'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl11','')">P/O Notified</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'IsExtension'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl12','')">Ext</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:left;"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00'), 'OpportunityStatusText'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl13','')">Status</a></th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:center;">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead><tbody>
    <tr class="rgRow" id="m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00__0">
        <td align="center"><img title="Time" src="images/Project_TandM.png"></td><td>calcutta</td><td><a href="/Default.aspx?Page=e8bb2a45-095a-4063-b46f-7b320a937eed&amp;Record=904daa2e-937c-44ec-9c70-ecf4a02951cb&amp;ParentPage=https://one.com" target="_self">NRK</a></td><td>1233</td><td><a href="/Default.aspx?Page=ec65cc03-1421-4fcf-bf6f-b726c46f85d1&amp;Record=97328b2f-f9b6-eb11-80f6-005056955ab7&amp;ParentPage=https://onesysaz.isg-one.com/Default.aspx?Page=003919e8-a01e-45db-b576-cb7da8a64586" target="_self">fixed price</a></td><td align="center"><img title="Closed - Won" src="images/Opportunity_ClosedWon.png"></td><td class="nowrap" align="right">123</td><td>Jerry</td><td class="nowrap">24 Nov 21</td><td class="nowrap">01 Dec 21</td><td>Jerry</td><td class="nowrap">24 Nov 21</td><td>No</td><td align="center"><img title="Not Started" src="images/statusRed.png"></td><td align="center"><input type="image" name="m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl05" src="images/magnify.gif" onclick="javascript:NavigateTo('/Default.aspx?Page=731c00ec-4851-4a93-9c43-b4891b983b02&amp;Record=97328B2F-F9B6-EB11-80F6-005056955AB7&amp;ParentPage=https://onesysaz.isg-one.com/Default.aspx?Page=003919e8-a01e-45db-b576-cb7da8a64586'); return false;"></td>
    </tr><tr class="rgAltRow" id="m_mc_s0_igSearch_ctl00_ctl00__1">
        <td align="center"><img title="Time" src="images/Project_TandM.png"></td><td>Bangalore</td><td><a href="/Default.aspx?Page=e8bb2a45-095a-4063-b46f-7b320a937eed&amp;Record=5c6b4ed8-c987-4910-888e-26aca79aed5a&amp;ParentPage=https://one.com" target="_self">Mercamer</a></td><td>1445</td><td><a href="/Default.aspx?Page=ec65cc03-1421-4fcf-bf6f-b726c46f85d1&amp;Record=01d6d3d6-8c1f-ec11-8107-0050569541a4&amp;ParentPage=https://onesysaz.isg-one.com/Default.aspx?Page=003919e8-a01e-45db-b576-cb7da8a64586" target="_self">extension</a></td><td align="center"><img title="Closed - Won" src="images/Opportunity_ClosedWon.png"></td><td class="nowrap" align="right">244</td><td>Tumbola</td><td class="nowrap">17 Nov 21</td><td class="nowrap">15 Nov 21</td><td>riti</td><td class="nowrap">16 Nov 21</td><td>No</td><td align="center"><img title="SOW missing Credit Worthiness" src="images/StatusCreditCheck.png"></td><td align="center"><input type="image" name="m$mc$s0$igSearch$ctl00$ctl00$ctl06$ctl05" src="images/magnify.gif" onclick="javascript:NavigateTo('/Default.aspx?Page=0e440aef-d76b-47d9-9f35-3952280cace5&amp;Record=E7A62ADA-2E9A-40B5-BDB2-E355969D41B7&amp;ParentPage=https://onesysaz.isg-one.com/Default.aspx?Page=003919e8-a01e-45db-b576-cb7da8a64586'); return false;"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a general principle.

Find the table first:

```
table = driver.find_element(By.CLASS, "rgMasterTable")
```

Second, look for whatever you need inside the table element:

for example:

```
rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG, "tr")
```

You can find all elements nested inside the table this way, no matter how many are there
Do whatever you need to do and apply you logics:

```
for row in rows: 
    outer = row.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    title = row.get_attribute("title")
```

You can also use range if needed.